# SetTimeout on browser close

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am having a legacy code which submits some data using following code.

```
 setTimeout(function ()
    {
     SubmitForm();
    }, 
    0);
```

Above block is there in Submit method. I want to execute this code even when browser is closed, so I am calling the same Submit method in onbeforeunload, but it doesn't execute the SubmitForm function. Any insights?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

If the browser is closed (or being closed) there is no wait time to wait for a form post to go through.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run JavaScript code in a browser (or any JavaSrcipt VM for that matter) after it has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do anything if the browser is closed, because there's nothing to run your code. Instead, you can use so called non-asynchronous ajax requests, without `setTimeout`. This can be done easily using the [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "[insert your php file path here]",
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        async: false,
    });
});
```

This will run right before the browser would be closed or the user would navigate away from your site.